# Storing HDFS data into MongoDB using Pig

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig, mongo-java-driver

I am new to Hadoop and having a requirement to store the Hadoop data into MongoDB. Here I am using Pig to store the data in Hadoop into MongoDB.

I downloaded and registered the following drivers to do this in Pig Grunt shell with the help of given command,

```
REGISTER /home/miracle/Downloads/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar
REGISTER /home/miracle/Downloads/mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar
REGISTER /home/miracle/Downloads/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar
```

After this I successfully got the data from MongoDB using the following command.

```
raw = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pavan.pavan.in' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader;
```

Then I tried the following command to insert the data from pig bag to MongoDB and got succeeded.

```
STORE student INTO 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pavan.persons_info' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoInsertStorage('','');
```

Then I am trying the Mongo Update using the below command.

```
STORE student INTO 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pavan.persons_info1' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage(' ','{first:"\$firstname", last:"\$lastname", phone:"\$phone", city:"\$city"}','firstname: chararray,lastname: chararray,phone: chararray,city: chararray');
```

But I am getting the below error while performing the above command.

```html
2017-03-22 11:16:42,516 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-03-22 11:16:43,064 [main] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: ; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:43,180 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2017-03-22 11:16:43,306 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-03-22 11:16:43,308 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2017-03-22 11:16:43,309 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2017-03-22 11:16:43,310 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2017-03-22 11:16:43,314 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2017-03-22 11:16:43,314 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2017-03-22 11:16:43,415 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-03-22 11:16:43,419 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-03-22 11:16:43,423 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2017-03-22 11:16:43,425 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2017-03-22 11:16:43,438 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2017-03-22 11:16:43,603 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/miracle/Downloads/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp159471787/tmp643027494/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:43,687 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/miracle/Downloads/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp159471787/tmp-1745369112/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:43,822 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/miracle/Downloads/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp159471787/tmp116725398/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:44,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/pig-0.16.0/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp159471787/tmp499355324/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:44,762 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/pig-0.16.0/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp159471787/tmp413788756/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:44,830 [DataStreamer for file /tmp/temp159471787/tmp-380031198/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar block BP-1303579226-127.0.1.1-1489750707340:blk_1073742392_1568] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
 at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:609)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeInternal(DFSOutputStream.java:577)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:573)
2017-03-22 11:16:44,856 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/pig-0.16.0/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp159471787/tmp-380031198/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:44,960 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig/pig-0.16.0/lib/joda-time-2.9.3.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp159471787/tmp1163422388/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:44,996 [main] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: ; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:45,004 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2017-03-22 11:16:45,147 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2017-03-22 11:16:45,166 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-03-22 11:16:45,253 [JobControl] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: ; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:45,318 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2017-03-22 11:16:45,572 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage - Using PigTextInputFormat
2017-03-22 11:16:45,579 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-03-22 11:16:45,581 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-03-22 11:16:45,593 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2017-03-22 11:16:45,690 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:1
2017-03-22 11:16:45,884 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_local1070093788_0006
2017-03-22 11:16:47,476 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606120/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar <- /home/miracle/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:47,534 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp159471787/tmp643027494/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar as file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606120/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:47,534 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606121/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar <- /home/miracle/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:47,674 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp159471787/tmp-1745369112/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar as file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606121/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,194 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606122/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar <- /home/miracle/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,201 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp159471787/tmp116725398/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar as file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606122/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,329 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606123/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar <- /home/miracle/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,337 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp159471787/tmp499355324/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar as file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606123/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,338 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606124/automaton-1.11-8.jar <- /home/miracle/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,370 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp159471787/tmp413788756/automaton-1.11-8.jar as file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606124/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,371 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606125/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar <- /home/miracle/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,384 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp159471787/tmp-380031198/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar as file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606125/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,389 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606126/joda-time-2.9.3.jar <- /home/miracle/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,409 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp159471787/tmp1163422388/joda-time-2.9.3.jar as file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606126/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,798 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606120/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,803 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606121/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,803 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606122/mongo-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,804 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606123/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,806 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606124/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,807 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606125/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,807 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/1490206606126/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2017-03-22 11:16:48,807 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2017-03-22 11:16:48,809 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local1070093788_0006
2017-03-22 11:16:48,812 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases student1
2017-03-22 11:16:48,812 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: student1[7,11] C:  R: 
2017-03-22 11:16:48,889 [Thread-455] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - OutputCommitter set in config null
2017-03-22 11:16:48,915 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2017-03-22 11:16:48,915 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_local1070093788_0006]
2017-03-22 11:16:48,999 [Thread-455] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: ; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:49,011 [Thread-455] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2017-03-22 11:16:49,013 [Thread-455] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2017-03-22 11:16:49,013 [Thread-455] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-03-22 11:16:49,054 [Thread-455] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - OutputCommitter is org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter
2017-03-22 11:16:49,094 [Thread-455] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/localRunner/miracle/job_local1070093788_0006/job_local1070093788_0006.xml; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:49,104 [Thread-455] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoOutputCommitter - Setting up job.
2017-03-22 11:16:49,126 [Thread-455] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Waiting for map tasks
2017-03-22 11:16:49,127 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Starting task: attempt_local1070093788_0006_m_000000_0
2017-03-22 11:16:49,253 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/localRunner/miracle/job_local1070093788_0006/job_local1070093788_0006.xml; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:49,279 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/localRunner/miracle/job_local1070093788_0006/job_local1070093788_0006.xml; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:49,290 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoOutputCommitter - Setting up task.
2017-03-22 11:16:49,296 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2017-03-22 11:16:49,340 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Processing split: Number of splits :1
Total Length = 212
Input split[0]:
   Length = 212
   ClassName: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit
   Locations:

-----------------------

2017-03-22 11:16:49,415 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage - Using PigTextInputFormat
2017-03-22 11:16:49,417 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader - Current split being processed hdfs://localhost:9000/input/student_dir/student_Info.txt:0+212
2017-03-22 11:16:49,459 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/localRunner/miracle/job_local1070093788_0006/job_local1070093788_0006.xml; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:49,684 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2017-03-22 11:16:50,484 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter - Writing to temporary file: /tmp/hadoop-miracle/attempt_local1070093788_0006_m_000000_0/_MONGO_OUT_TEMP/_out
2017-03-22 11:16:50,516 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Preparing to write to com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter@1fd6ae6
2017-03-22 11:16:50,736 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Selected heap (Tenured Gen) of size 699072512 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489350752, usageThreshold = 489350752
2017-03-22 11:16:50,739 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2017-03-22 11:16:50,746 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: student1[7,11] C:  R: 
2017-03-22 11:16:50,880 [Thread-455] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map task executor complete.
2017-03-22 11:16:50,919 [Thread-455] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage - Store location config: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/tmp/hadoop-miracle/mapred/local/localRunner/miracle/job_local1070093788_0006/job_local1070093788_0006.xml; for namespace: pavan.persons_info1; hosts: [localhost:27017]
2017-03-22 11:16:50,963 [Thread-455] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1070093788_0006
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Couldn't convert tuple to bson: 
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Couldn't convert tuple to bson: 
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.StoreFuncDecorator.putNext(StoreFuncDecorator.java:83)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:144)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:97)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map.collect(PigMapOnly.java:48)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:261)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:65)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't convert tuple to bson: 
 at com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage.putNext(MongoUpdateStorage.java:165)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.StoreFuncDecorator.putNext(StoreFuncDecorator.java:75)
 ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at org.apache.pig.data.DefaultTuple.get(DefaultTuple.java:117)
 at com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.JSONPigReplace.substitute(JSONPigReplace.java:120)
 at com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage.putNext(MongoUpdateStorage.java:142)
 ... 18 more
2017-03-22 11:16:53,944 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2017-03-22 11:16:53,944 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local1070093788_0006 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2017-03-22 11:16:53,945 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2017-03-22 11:16:53,949 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-03-22 11:16:53,954 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-03-22 11:16:53,962 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2017-03-22 11:16:53,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion PigVersion UserId StartedAt FinishedAt Features
2.7.3 0.16.0 miracle 2017-03-22 11:16:43 2017-03-22 11:16:53 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId Alias Feature Message Outputs
job_local1070093788_0006 student1 MAP_ONLY Message: Job failed! mongodb://localhost:27017/pavan.persons_info1,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost:9000/input/student_dir/student_Info.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "mongodb://localhost:27017/pavan.persons_info1"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1070093788_0006


2017-03-22 11:16:53,983 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2017-03-22 11:16:54,004 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias student1
Details at logfile: /home/miracle/pig_1490205716326.log
```

Here is the input that I have dumped here,

```
Input(s):
```

Successfully read 6 records (5378419 bytes) from: "hdfs://localhost:9000/input/student_dir/student_Info.txt"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 6 records (5378449 bytes) in: "hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp-1419179625/tmp882976412"

Counters:
Total records written : 6
Total bytes written : 5378449
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1866034015_0001

2017-03-23 02:43:37,677 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-03-23 02:43:37,681 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-03-23 02:43:37,689 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-03-23 02:43:37,736 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2017-03-23 02:43:37,748 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-03-23 02:43:37,751 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2017-03-23 02:43:37,793 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-03-23 02:43:37,793 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
**(Rajiv,Reddy,9848022337,Hyderabad)
(siddarth,Battacharya,9848022338,Kolkata)
(Rajesh,Khanna,9848022339,Delhi)
(Preethi,Agarwal,9848022330,Pune)
(Trupthi,Mohanthy,9848022336,Bhuwaneshwar)
(Archana,Mishra,9848022335,Chennai.)**

I don't know What to do next please give me any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

*I do not use Mongo , but from  HBase experience and  From the error it looks like few fields are not flatten 'ed enough for it to fit the column family. And also few of columns you are trying to STORE don't exist. 
See to DUMP the data instead of STORE and check if it is matching the STORE structure you have applied.*

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't convert tuple to bson:   at
>   com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage.putNext(MongoUpdateStorage.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.StoreFuncDecorator.putNext(StoreFuncDecorator.java:75)
>     ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1,
>   Size: 1   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)   at
>   org.apache.pig.data.DefaultTuple.get(DefaultTuple.java:117)   at
>   com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.JSONPigReplace.substitute(JSONPigReplace.java:120)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoUpdateStorage.putNext(MongoUpdateStorage.java:142)
>     ... 18 more

Comment: Hi Sandesh thanks for replying back  to me I have edited my question and added the Dump please check it.